# How do I remove the last character of an R-T-L string in python?

Tags: python, string, unicode, right-to-left

I am trying to remove the last character of a string in a "right-to-left" language. When I do, however, the last character wraps to the beginning of the string.
e.g.
`ותֵיהֶם]׃`
becomes
`ותֵיהֶם]`

I know that this is a fundamental issue with how I'm handling the R-T-L paradigm, but if someone could help me think through it, I'd very much appreciate it.

**CODE**

```
with open(r"file.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = unicode(line,'utf-8')
        the_text = line.split('\t')[1]
        the_text.replace(u'\u05C3','')
```

Comment: Could you give us the value of `#some unicode object`? How are you storing the string (as r-t-l, or l-t-r but with the convention that it's to be rendered r-t-l)?

Comment: Apologies. `#some unicode object` is actually the string in the first paragraph (`ותֵיהֶם]׃`). I updated my code to reflect how I'm getting the object in the first place.

Comment: in r-t-l the last character is the first on the left, correct? doesn't line[1:] work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some characters in Unicode are always LTR, some are always RTL, and some can be either depending on their surrounding context.  In addition, the display context for bidirectional text will have a "predominant" directionality (e.g. a text editor configured for mainly-English text would be predominantly LTR and have a ragged right margin, one configured for mainly-Hebrew would be predominantly RTL with a ragged left margin).

It looks like what has happened here is that when a closing square bracket character appears between two RTL characters it is rendered in its RTL form (your first example) but when it appears between a RTL and a LTR character (or at the end of the string - basically, somewhere where it doesn't have other characters of the same directionality on both sides) then it is considered to be part of whichever run of text matches the predominant direction.  If you try dragging your mouse over the string to select the characters you'll see that *logically* the closing `]` still follows the `ֶם` even if *visually* it appears to have moved.

If the second-to-last character in your string were also a Hebrew character (or other strongly RTL character) rather than a `]`, or if the display context was predominantly RTL, then it would appear where you expect it to.

Comment: +1. To fix this, by the way, if the bidi-rendering library doesn't offer a way to tell it "this is a predominately RTL text", one option is to add U+200F, the Unicode [right-to-left mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark), to the start and end of the string right before render-time. (Not a perfect solution, but likely to work for typical purposes.) **Edited to add:** Or, similarly, to write `replace(u'\u05C3',u'\u200F')` instead of `replace(u'\u05C3','')` (though that risks creating more such programmer-confusion later on).

Comment: @ruakh and Ian ... thank you both so much for both the theory and the practical resolution